# Error while implementing update of data in database for rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am trying to implement a shopping list in ruby on rails.I have created two tables in the database, `products` and `shopping_list`. I have given products a foreign key reference of shopping_list which is `product.shopping_list_id`.

I am trying to find the `total products` present in the `shopping list` in ruby on rails but I am getting an error.

My create Shop schema is as follows:-

```
class CreateShopSchema < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

        # --------------------

        # Table Name: shopping_list
        # --------------------
        # Note: This is the base table that has details about an account.
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------

    create_table :shopping_lists do |t|
            t.string     :id, :null => false
            t.string     :shopping_list_name
            t.string     :shopping_list_status, :default => 'OPEN'          
            t.string     :total_items, :default => 0
            t.timestamps
    end

        # --------------------
        # Table Name: products
        # --------------------
        # Note: This is the base table that has details about an account.
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------

    create_table :products do |t|
            t.references :shopping_list, :null => false
            t.string     :product_name,  :default => 'null'
            t.string     :product_category
            t.integer    :quantity          
            t.string     :status, :default => 'OPEN' 
    end


  end

  def down
    drop_table :products
    drop_table :shopping_lists
  end

end
```

My shopping_list table is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_lists
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  shopping_list_name character varying(255),
  shopping_list_status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'OPEN'::character varying,
  total_items character varying(255) DEFAULT 0,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT shopping_lists_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My product table is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  shopping_list_id integer NOT NULL,
  product_name character varying(255) DEFAULT 'null'::character varying,
  product_category character varying(255),
  quantity integer,
  status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'OPEN'::character varying,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My product controller is as follows:-

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
  @products = Product.all
   # @products = Product.includes(:shopping_list_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end  

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   #product = Product.includes(:shopping_list_id)
   #@product = Product.joins(:shopping_list_id)


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json


def delete
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.deleted = 1
    @product.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
    end
  end

  def list
   @products = Product.find(:all,
                 :order => "id asc")
  # @products = Product.includes(:shopping_list_id)



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => 'list' }
      format.json { render :json => @accounts.to_json }
    end       
  end

 end
```

When I am trying to add new products in the database via the front end ,the product table is populated but the quantity(total items) in shopping_list is not getting updated in the database.

I want to implement in such a way so that I can get the count of the products of the particular shopping list

Can anyone please help me implement this

Answer (score 1):

Okay why don't you consider setting your application as the following:

**Product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category 
belongs_to :shopping_list


def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
```

**Category.rb**

```
has_many :products
```

**Line_item**

```
belongs_to :product 
belongs_to :shopping_list 
belongs_to :order --> will let you finish the rest
```

**shopping_list.rb**

```
has_many :line_items
```

Your order table will include `quantity`. To get the `quantity` of what is in your order you would do something like the following:

```
def quantity
    line_items.to_a.sum { |quant| quant.quantity }
  end
```

Putting the above inside your product model will mean you will be able to do in your `product/index.html.erb` --> `<%= order.quantity %>`

Comment: where do I put
 def quantity
    line_items.to_a.sum { |quant| quant.quantity }
  end

in Product.rb? @Djj

Comment: No in the Order table. Effectively you will have the following relations `Products`, `Category`, `line_item`, `shopping_list` and `Order`.

Comment: But I will not be able to implement the relation in my application?
I will have to start off from scratch @Djj

Comment: it is still giving me an error

can you tell me if I can add the following query in rails format:-

total_items=Select count(*) from products where shopping_list_id is [] @Djj

Comment: What are you counting here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25155/discussion-between-arsenew-and-djj)

Comment: i want to display total products for the particular shopping list

Comment: You after something like this - `Product.where(:shopping_list_id => nil).count`

Comment: In your product controller and then call it

Comment: I have updated the question.Please check it.Where do I put it

Comment: do you have the solution for my problems